# No SMTP credentials option

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I am trying to set up the "Extended E-mail Notification" in jenkins. My plugin version is [2.89](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKFK5.png)

However in the setup i dont see the SMTP Authentication checkbox, instead it just has this credentials tab. [Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj84x.png)

I tried to use my office365 credentials but it is just using the jenkins user for some reason.
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5tQz.png)

Does anyone know how to set up the plugin?

Comment: Beside the Credentials field, there's a key and "Add". Use that to add your credentials there and it stores them in the Credentials files, which makes them available to the plugin.

Comment: Also, don't add a picture unless it adds value to the Q. The plugin version image does not. And don't paste images of text (esp. logs). Paste the text "as code" so it's easier to read and detachable. Welcome.